# Oracle sql count() function?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, conditional-statements

I have a problem with the function count(). I want to it to count only under specific conditions.

What i want to do is to display for each company, the company's name, the name of the company's boss and the number of rentals exceeding three days made in 2010.

So the condition is: the number of rentals exceeding three days made in 2010.

Therefore, if the company doesn't have any rentals that satisfy the condition, it shouldn't be eliminated form the resulting table but instead it should be written zero. For example:

```
company 1 -------------------- BOSS 1-----------------------2
company 2---------------------- BOSS 2---------------------- 0 --doesn't satisfy the condition: 0 rentals
company 3-----------------------BOSS 3 ----------------------5
company 4---------------------- BOSS 4--------------------------1
company 4 ----------------------BOSS 5 ----------------------- 0 --doesn't satisfy the condition: 0 rentals

AND NOT

company 1----------------------BOSS 1---------------------------2
company 3--------------------- BOSS 3---------------------------5
company 4----------------------BOSS 4 --------------------------1
```

My sql codes displays the second table and not the first table. This is my code:

```
SELECT ag.nom_agence as NOM_AGENCE, ag.responsable_agence, count(*) as RESPONSABLE
FROM agences ag, locations l
WHERE ag.id_agence = l.id_agence AND
      l.date_location BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND to_date('31/12/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND
      l.duree > 3
      group by ag.nom_agence,ag.responsable_agence
```

I want something of this format (without the where clause):

```
count(l.date_location BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND to_date('31/12/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND
          l.duree > 3)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an outer join to the locations table to make sure you always pull in all rentals in the period irrespective of their length.

Then count the number of rentals > 3 days.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  NOM_AGENCE, 
  RESP_AGENCE,
  SUM(RESPONSABLE)
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      ag.nom_agence as NOM_AGENCE, 
      ag.responsable_agence RESP_AGENCE, 
      CASE  
        WHEN l.duree > 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END RESPONSABLE
    FROM 
      agences ag LEFT OUTER JOIN locations l ON ag.id_agence = l.id_agence 
                                             AND l.date_location 
                                             BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') 
                                             AND to_date('31/12/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') 
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  NOM_AGENCE,
  RESP_AGENCE
```

Comment: `l.duree > 3` isn't filtering it out. Actually I need it to satisfy the condition `the number of rentals exceeding three days`. But the `WHERE` clause is limiting the results

Comment: try my latest edit, should work now - I was a bit confused by the original query

Comment: It didn't really work `(error:missing keyword)` but it gave me an idea on how to use `case`.

Comment: sorry, cut and paste error, I had left a count(*) in after `else 0` which shouldn't have been there.. does it work now?

Comment: There's a problem with the group by clause. `agences ag` is defined in the brackets so `ag.nom_agence` and `ag.nom_responsble` is undefined

Comment: I found the answer. It gives me the right table. Unfortunately I can't answer my question because i have less than 100 reutation. Here's the code `SELECT ag.nom_agence as NOM_AGENCE, ag.responsable_agence as RESPONSABLE,
count(case when to_char(l.date_location, 'YYYY') = '2010' and l.duree>3 then 1 end) as NOMBRE
FROM agences ag
left outer join locations l on  ag.id_agence = l.id_agence
      group by nom_agence, responsable_agence `

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (I did not try it).

It's basically and outer join between the agencies table and the rentals grouped by agency following your search filter.

The NVL transforms the count for the agencies that don't have a match in the right query to a 0.

```
select left.id_agence, left.nom_agence, left.responsable_agence, NVL(right.count, 0)
from
(select id_agence, nom_agence, responsable_agence from agences) left
left outer join 
(
  SELECT id_agence, count(*) as count
  FROM locations
  WHERE date_location BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND     to_date('31/12/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND
      duree > 3
  group by id_agence
) right
on left.id_agence = right.id_agence
```

Comment: It works but i don't understand the `NVL` clause. Seems to advanced for me lol. I just started learning Oracle sql. Thanks though :)

Comment: @mkab, NVL simply substitutes a value by another if the value is null. For instance, NVL(3, 4) will return 3 as 3 is not null but NVL(NULL, 12) will return 12. As outer joins produce null values where the datasets value don't match, NVL allows us to treat them as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the having clause:

```
having count(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My quick answer is that you have to do LEFT JOIN and not INNER JOIN that you do. Try this:

```
SELECT ag.nom_agence as NOM_AGENCE, ag.responsable_agence, count(*) as RESPONSABLE
FROM agences ag
left join locations l on l.id_agence = ag.id_agence
WHERE 
  l.date_location BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND                                                                       

  to_date('31/12/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND
           l.duree > 3
group by ag.nom_agence,ag.responsable_agence
```

Comment: Same problem. The `WHERE` clause is limiting the results. It gives me the same table as `the inner join`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ag.nom_agence as NOM_AGENCE, ag.responsable_agence, count(*) as RESPONSABLE
FROM agences ag LEFT OUTER JOIN locations l ON ag.id_agence = l.id_agence 
WHERE l.date_location BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND to_date('31/12/2010','DD.MM.YYYY') AND l.duree > 3 
group by ag.nom_agence,ag.responsable_agence
```

The key is you need to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN which will retrieve all records from your agences table regardless of whether there are any matching records in locations

Comment: Same problem. The `WHERE` clause is limiting the results. It gives me the same table as `the inner join`

Answer (score -1):

I found the query. It gives me the right table

```
SELECT ag.nom_agence as NOM_AGENCE, ag.responsable_agence as RESPONSABLE, count(case when to_char(l.date_location, 'YYYY') = '2010' and l.duree>3 then 1 end) as NOMBRE
FROM agences ag, locations l
WHERE ag.id_agence = l.id_agence
      group by nom_agence, responsable_agence
```

Thanks for your help, everyone.